# Angular: How to import JitCompilerFactory?

Tags: angular, aot, angular-compiler, angular-dynamic-components

If I use AOT compilation dynamic compilation will not possible. So I need to load the compiler to a browser. So how do I load it? If I use

```
import { JitCompilerFactory } from '@angular/compiler';
```

However, after importing the `JitCompilerFactory` I am getting the following error:

> "export 'JitCompilerFactory' was not found in 'angular/compiler

So am I right that now I need to import it from `'angular/platform-browser-dynamic'` for dynamic compilation?

Comment: Did [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51585753/2545680) answer help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import `JitCompilerFactory` into your **app.module.ts** like this:

```
import {Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory} from '@angular/core';
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
export function createCompiler(compilerFactory: CompilerFactory) {
  return compilerFactory.createCompiler();
}



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
    {provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here I created a fully working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-zyns9l) with a Dynamic Component if you want to play around with it on there.

Comment: @angularindepth-com yes, it helped.

Comment: Thanks for this example. One thing to note is that `core-js` has changed its import paths in `3.0.1`. I had to add this to my polyfills.ts: `import 'core-js/es/reflect'; import 'core-js/stable/reflect'; import 'core-js/features/reflect';`.

Comment: @Narm I'm trying this example, but getting an error:

```
ERROR Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'DynamicComponentModule'.
```
I think I'm doing it exactly the same way as you're doing it, plus I updated the dependencies on your example like they are on my project and it's still working for you, but not for me. Any idea on what else I should take care of?

Comment: @Narm Actually, when I run ng serve --aot=true on your project, then I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Hi @gencblakqori, the comment section to this question isn't the correct forum to answer these questions. If you create your own question with your unique problem I can take a look at it and we can discuss it there.

Comment: Hi @Narm, it's the same topic. You're also doing dynamic compilation. In fact I just downloaded your code from StackBlitz and ran `ng serve --aot` and it didn't work. It showed me the error above.